# Custom URL schema doesn't open app

Tags: iphone, ios, url, schema, openurl

I have a problem with custom URL schema. I think I've configured it properly but it doesn't open the app if it is closed, if the app is in "background" (i.e. I can see it double tapping the home button) the app is opened when I tap on the link.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>com.test</string>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>test</string>
<string>test1</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

the link is

```
<a href="test://this_is_a_test">TEST</a>
```

other applications work fine but not mine.

Thanks,
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Do you `return NO;` anywhere in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method?

I can't think of anything that would cause it to not open, aside from returning `NO`.

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",url,sourceApplication);
    return YES; 
}`

this is the code I use. I've downloaded a sample sender & receiver app and works fine...